# Boot linux over the network using WDS

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, wds

I am looking to boot Linux (Ubuntu, Gentoo, and some others) over the network. I already have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine running a few programs including Windows Deployment Services. This is set so I can install Windows over the network.

I basically want to use any Linux ISO and it will be able to run it over the network. I don't want to install Linux, only boot. E.g. the Ubuntu live CD.

Answer (score 1):

The DHCP server is providing the PXE client with PXE boot parameters - mainly a TFTP server IP address and an image filename to load. Your Windows Server system would by default provide the clients with the WDS bootstrap for Windows installations.

There is a way to change this behavior for particular clients by using [wdsutil /set-device](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/jose_aguilar_blog/archive/2007/05/16/1442.aspx). Setting the image name to a [pxelinux](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/PXELINUX) bootstrap and [configuring your network boot environment for Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) should enable live booting for Linux. You probably would want an NFS server as well.